# Webdriver/NUnit C#: take text from page and add to log along with test name?

Tags: c#, selenium, logging, nunit, reporting

I am trying to do something like this during my Webdriver test:

- Run test
- At page 2 of the test, get a specific string of text from the page source (not displayed on front end), take that string and add it to a text log along with the NUnit test name and any other attributes that could be useful

So the output would be something like 'log.txt' and would show:

```
[TESTCASE1] 'String lifted from page source'
```

Comment: What is the part you are stuck with?

Comment: The whole thing - I am new to this and have never tried to implement something like this, so I need to know how to get data and write to file

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward, decide what `path` your file will be written, and then just use `streamwriter` to write it.

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, "log.txt");
string yourMessage = "";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(yourMessage);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
{
    writer.Write(sb);
}
```

If you want your test case's name, take a look at the `TestContext` object that comes with every test. More information [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.7).

Comment: This looks great, I will try it out - thank you. Would you be able to explain how I could also obtain a string from the source of the web page if possible?

Comment: What do you mean "from the source of the web page"? Do you want the text of an element? Or a text that only exists in the source code and is no-where on the visible(to the user) page.

If you want a text from an element, it's easy to get it, but if you want an HTML comment that does not show anywhere in the screen, I don't have any ideas on how to get it. Google can be your friend tho. "Selenium how to take source code", and then maybe search it through the code? Explain a bit more or give us an example and maybe we can help.